# Keep PyQt UI Responsive With Threads

Tags: python, multithreading, user-interface, crash, python-multithreading

I have created a relatively complex PyQt program and am trying to implement threads so that when the program encounters a part of the program which is particularly CPU intensive, the GUI will remain refreshed and responsive throughout. Sadly though, I am having some difficulties with the threading.

I am using Python 2.7 for reasons that I don't believe to be relevant.

Anyway, the entire program runs within one class and calls upon a PyQt designer .ui file in order to display the actual GUI. When a particular button is pressed, in order to shred a file, it calls a function within that class that then starts a thread using the 'thread' module, yes, outdated, I know. The shredding function that is then called from this commences the shredding of the file. Throughout the shredding of the file, the actual shredding function interacts and adds bits to the GUI in order to keep the user up to date on what is happening.

During the execution of the function the GUI continues to be refreshed, however it does become a little laggy, I can cope with that. However, when that function is complete, instead of smoothly continuing and allowing the user to keep using the program, the program throws a complete hissy fit and simply just stops working and has to be closed.

Hopefully someone can assist me here. I would greatly appreciate as much detail as possible as I have been searching around for a way to cope with this for a good number of weeks now.

I am using PyQt4.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please provide a [Minimal, Complete and Working](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of your code so we can better help you!

Comment: Have you tried adding print statements in the main thread to display information about the status of the program -- i.e. what exactly it's trying to do, how much memory is in use, how much CPU is in use, etc.?

Comment: You might consider these alternatives to using threads for heavy CPU use.  1. Divide the CPU work into chunks of say, .01 second and yield control back to the GUI after scheduling the next chunk.  In tkinter, one would use root.after.  In 3.4+ asyncio, loop.soon.  2. Use multiprocessing instead of threading.  On a multi-core machine, it can run on another core.  If 'shredding files' means what I think, your actual problem may be blocking on disk i/o, rather than CPU use.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple demo of threading in pyqt5. Qt has it's own threading class that works pretty well.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal
import sys
import time

class TheBoss(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TheBoss, self).__init__(parent)
        self.resize(300,200)
        self.VL = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.VL.addWidget(self.label)
        self.logger = Logger()
        self.logger.sec_signal.connect(self.label.setText)
        self.logger.start()

    def closeEvent(self,event):
        self.logger.terminate()

class Logger(QtCore.QThread):
    sec_signal = pyqtSignal(str)
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Logger, self).__init__(parent)
        self.current_time = 0
        self.go = True
    def run(self):
        #this is a special fxn that's called with the start() fxn
        while self.go:
            time.sleep(1)
            self.sec_signal.emit(str(self.current_time))
            self.current_time += 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setApplicationName("Thread Example")
    window = TheBoss()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```